# Placing HTML code inside while loop correctly

Tags: php

I have an HTML video player (see code below) with some Javascript ([see code here](https://codeshare.io/1YDezX)). My video files are recorded inside a database (see below)

[image]

**Here is my HTML code:**

```
<video class="videoPlayer" id="videoplaylist" preload="auto" tabindex="0" controls="">
    <source src="video1.mp4">
</video>
<ul id="playlist">
    <li>
    <a href="video2.mp4"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="video3.mp4"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to loop through the videos from the database but with the correct HTML structure code above. I'm having issues placing the code correctly inside the while loop. In the future if more videos are were to be added into the database - the only thing that would be added would be more **li** (list items) under the "playlist" id.

**For example:**

```
<li>
<a href="video4.mp4"></a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="video5.mp4"></a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="video6.mp4"></a>
</li>
```

**Here is my SELECT sql with a while loop**

```
$sql = "SELECT title, video_src FROM videos WHERE username = 'admin' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    // HTML VIDEO PLAYER CODE NEEDS TO GO HERE
    echo $row['src'];

  }
} else {
  echo "no video results found";
}
```

Comment: `echo '<li><a href="'.$row['src'].'"></a></li>';`???

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol thanks for the quick reply! Yes, that would work. The issue i think I'm facing is what about the <video> in the beginning. if I put that inside the while loop it's going to loop that 3 times but it only needs to appear the one time.

Comment: @code if you need video player appears once then place it outside the loop ( above while ) and rest of the logic inside the loop

Comment: Yeah, I don't... get it. If you want something not to be looped, just don't put it in the loop, put it before the loop?

Comment: Sorry! That I understand. Take a look here https://codeshare.io/Adg41l I edited what you guys are mentioning but the <source src="'.$row['src'].'"> is outside the loop. I wouldn't be able to get that from the database. The video files are going to be named differently all the time.

Comment: Oh, if you want to use the first row separately, just put a `$row = $result->fetch_assoc();` before that. That'll get the first row, which you can use for the `<source />` tag, and then the loop will just run over the remaining rows.

Answer (score 0):

Added your HTML code in while loop:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      // output data of each row
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    
        echo '<li>
    <a href="'.htmlspecialchars($row['src']).'"></a>
    </li>';
       
    
      }
    } else {
      echo "no video results found";
    }
```

Outside the loop/without loop:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
          
     $row = $result->fetch_assoc()
        
      echo '<li><a href="'.htmlspecialchars($row['src']).'"></a></li>';
           
        
  
   } else {
          echo "no video results found";
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply answer! I understand this :) but maybe I didn't explain it correctly. Take a look at https://codeshare.io/Adg41l I updated my code. The <video> with the <source src="'.$row['src'].'"> in the beginning can only display once and if I put that inside the while loop it's going to repeat itself how many times the loop runs for.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I'm trying to place the HTML code I mentioned in the original post inside the loop like you showed me but I cannot have the <video> element inside the loop because then it's going to loop it how many times the loop will run for. It only needs to show once (outside the loop) BUT then how would I place '.$row['src']; inside the source src attribute to get the first result in the database. Does that make sense?

Comment: @code Added without loop solution. Please check it

Answer (score 0):

use the below code to create list. As I can see in your sql query, column name is `video_src`

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo '<ul>';
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<li><a href="'.htmlspecialchars($row['video_src']).'"></a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```